# Jquery hiding elements with specific classname that do not match a certain condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page which has multiple elements that all have the same classname.

Some of them are being repositioned  and when I submit the page I would like to hide the elements which are at a position of top: 0;

I've been looking at some suggestions and I've tried something like this:

```
$('.myClass').not($('.myClass').css('top', '0')).fadeOut(300);
```

But appearantly that's not working :-)

Anybody else has an idea on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: `$('.myClass').css('top', '0')` sets the top of the elements, not look for elements that have that value.

Comment: `.not(($('.myClass').css('top') == 0))`

Comment: @mtizziani that would only return the first... So that is also wrong.

Comment: Thanks mtizziani, but that actually fades out all of my elements with the same class which doesn'tmake sense but probably I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: ah, i see. i think you cant directly make this with css parameters and have to use a loop over the elements. not function only takes jquery nodes and not true or false as parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting the position top of the elements, not filtering the set.

You want to use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$( '.myClass' )
  .filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('top') === "0px";
  }).fadeOut(300);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no selector for this but this can be accomplished with by looping the elements and checking for the top [position](https://api.jquery.com/position/).

Something like this.

```
$.each($('.myClass'), function(i, el) {
  var position = $(el).position();

  if (position.top === 0) {
      $(el).hide();
  }
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pasgbdrs/)

Comment: @espacarello Yes I was working on the fiddle and saw it. Thank you! Anyway, your answer is better. + 1 for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Loop over every element with the class then check for its css property:

```
$('.myClass').each(function(){
  if($(this).css('top')==='0'){
     $(this).fadeOut(300);
  }
});
```